# Resize image into square div keeping aspect ratio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, flexbox, scaling, centering

I need in my application to insert images into square div of given size and I want them to show full, without cropping any part of it. At the moment I've got a javascript code that if the image is portrait (height > width) then set the height to 100% and width to auto, if it is landscape (width > height) set width to 100% and height to auto

http://jsfiddle.net/z7L6m2sc/583/

This is a link where I tried to reproduce my code(it's in erb and coffee because I'm developing a rails application, and I don't know why but the images are not centered inside the div(in my application this code works great!)

This is my code in rails

ERB

```
<div class="img">
  <% if i.insertion_images.length > 0 %>
    <%= image_tag(i.insertion_images[i.first_img].image.url(:medium), class: 'last_img')%>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is Coffee

```
$('.last_img').on 'load', ->
      natHeight = $(this).get(0).naturalHeight
      natWidth = $(this).get(0).naturalWidth
      if (natWidth > natHeight)
        $(this).css( 'width','100%')
        $(this).css( 'height','auto')
      else #if (natWidth < natHeight)
        $(this).css( 'height','100%')
        $(this).css( 'width','auto')
```

And this is the scss

```
img {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      last_img {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        bottom: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
        right: -9999px;
        margin: auto;
      }
    }
```

I started using flex for my layout, so my question is, Is possible to achieve this behavior with flex component? Maybe without all JS code and the -9999 in css

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `max-height: 100%` and `max-width: 100%` on the `.image-resize`, and I believe it would give you the results you're after. If you want to be safe, you could also add `width: auto` and `height: auto`.

```css
.img-container{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background:red;
  position: relative;
}

.image-resize {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/landscape-photography-1.jpg" class="image-resize"/>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="img-container">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/05/1c/11/051c110d463b1c4afb11ca003a6237a3--nice-girl-beautiful-body.jpg" class="image-resize"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using CSS if you don't mind setting the image as a background.

```css
.bg-image{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;  
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center; 
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image img-1" style="background-image: url(http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/landscape-photography-1.jpg)"></div>
<div class="bg-image img-2" style="background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/736x/05/1c/11/051c110d463b1c4afb11ca003a6237a3--nice-girl-beautiful-body.jpg)" ></div>
```